# Periodic Orbits in planar Hamiltonian Systems

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have to demonstrate the following statement:
"Consider a planar Hamiltonian System, with function of Hamilton H.
Let be C the connected component of a level curve $\{H=c\}$
Suppose that: C is not empty, compact and don't contains any equilibrium point.
Then C is the image of a periodic orbit".

I have prove that C contains the image of a periodic orbit, but i'm not able to demonstrate that the equal holds...

Comment: Please write up what you have proved so far. Also, please refrain from posting on mathoverflow and here at the same time.